# Study a portion of the image and not the white background

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter

*Disclaimer: This question is related to an homework project.*

I am working on an application to study a banana and tell if it is ripe or not. I have already created a window that allow to open an image, and open a popup saying if clicked pixel are ripe or not. I convert pixel rgb values to hsv and diagnose  whether it is ripe or not.

[image: snapshot of application]

Now, I would like to provide an automated analysis of the whole picture (in `analyseauto` method). The problem is that I want studying banana pixels only, and not white. My question is how I can select just a part of pixels, so the banana and not the white background. Can I do that with `getdata` ?

Here are relevant piece of code.

```
def analyseauto():
    global image
    listTriplets=list(image.getdata()) # list of rgb values
    print(listTriplets)

#click callback
def pointeur(event):
    global image

    x=str(event.x)
    y=str(event.y)
    x1=int(x)
    y1=int(y)

    R,V,B=image.getpixel((x1,y1)) 

    #convert to HSV (my T hold hue, from french "teinte")
    #[...]
    #update side text field
    #[...]

    Mûre = 0
    PasMûre = 0
    Pourri = 0
    AnalyseManuelle = 0
    PixelNoBanane = 0
    x2=0

    #diagnose
    # m value (between 1 and 4) record pixel state
    if 0<=T<=360 and 0<=S<=100 and 0<=V<=100:
        if 40<= T <=56 and 50<= S <=100 and 70<= V <=100:
            print("Il s'agit d'un pixel Mûre ")
            Mûre = Mûre+1
            x2 = x2+1
            m=1
            m=int(m)

        if 50<= T <=100 and 70<= S <=100 and 20<= V <=70:
            print("Il s'agit d'un pixel pas Mûre")
            PasMûre = PasMûre+1
            x2 = x2+1
            m=2
            m=int(m)

        if 0<= T <=30 and 70<= S <=100 and 10<= V <=50:
            print("Il s'agit d'un pixel Pourri")
            Pourri = Pourri+1
            x2 = x2+1
            m=3
            m=int(m)

    if x2 == 0 :
        print ("le pixel n'est pas compris dans les echelles definis")
        PixelNoBanane = PixelNoBanane+1
        m=4
        m=int(m)

    # display popup with plain text answer
```

Full application code available [on gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d12fd948ea3f3f06f557). Example of banana I use for testing:
[image] .

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's twitlonger doing it but your code is lacking indentation. You'll want to clean this up first. After that you'll want to identify any white pixels and discard them, collecting all of the non-white pixels and then averaging.

Comment: While averaging, use only the pixels that has r+g+b<=3*250, for example. You should tune the threshold value (250).

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @jww I am not sure what is your point adding this link. According the most popular answer there, user3592221 fullfill the spec for asking homework: good faith attempt to solve the problem, ask a specific question (yet not well worded) and  disclose it is homework. (I can not commit on school policy and its understanding of existing code). The same answer also state later "*Don't* downvote a homework question that follows the guidelines and was asked in good faith". The question have severe layout problem (and the hold is justified), but I wonder if downvoters spotted something I have missed

Comment: @FabienAndre - I presume he was downvoted because (1) it was a homework question; (2) it does not provide code. I'm just guessing though. I voted to close because there was no code. It was not clear what he was asking without a code context (to me). I provided the link for him to learn how to ask homework questions, so that help might be proffered. (For completeness, I did not downvote. I rarely do that. I've only cast 8 in my time here).

Comment: might desserve reopening (and recast vote?) after a substantial edit.

Comment: @user3592221 I have taken the liberty to edit your post so that it match SO standards. You are obviously allowed to correct me if I do not well capture your intent. Problems in your posts were: unclear question, lack of code snippet (optional though), the code you linked was unusable since not indented. It is important to show that you have tried something and search before asking, especially regarding homework questions. That said, even while respecting the standards, some will downvote homework question. You can specify that you are looking for hint and not full solution to avoid it.

Comment: It is my first time pn this website, so i didn't know how to include code etc

Comment: The problem is, that i have to work on the banana and not on the background, so i want to get data only from the banana

Answer (score 1):

I think using `getdata` is an acceptable way of doing what you want, but I think you should resize your image first. `getdata` will return a list, but at the current image size:

```
>>> banana = Image.open('banana.jpg')
>>> banana
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=847x567 at 0x2C26440>
```

That list will have pixel values of 480,249 pixels, which might be a little overkill.

If you resize it to 50x50:

```
>>> banana = banana.resize((50,50))
```

Then use `getdata`:

```
>>> banana = banana.resize((50,50))
>>> pixels = banana.getdata()
>>> len(pixels)
2500
>>> pixels = set(pixels) # remove duplicates
>>> len(pixels)
670
```

That seems more manageable. Then, just dump the (255,255,255) value from the set, and maybe any light gray colors, and get the average value to represent the color you want to test, and run your test as before (on just a single pixel's RGB value).

Hope I understood right and this helps.

Comment: `len` measures the length of the list `pixels`. I turned the list into a `set` to remove duplicates. As you said this is homework, I don't think I should give you a complete working code sample. However, you have the underlying logic to complete the problem, so filling in the pieces will just require some searching and learning about things that will ultimately benefit you.